# Tezos nodes being disconnected

Tags: node

Recently we have been having issues with some of the nodes being disconnected all the time. They sometimes pull and push some blocks and sometimes don't even have time to do it.

Generally, the logs show something like:

> validator.chain: Disconnection of idtKX8X3RMGtubZyZZgg6NaS4H6Ay9

I can see some logs of unknown ancestors as well.

We tried to add new address bootstrap peers but that didn't work.
Some ideas about what can be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Peers connecting and disconnecting is a normal thing in P2P networks. Best thing you can do is increase your max number of connections (`tezos-node config update --connections 100`), and use the [addpeers.sh](https://gist.github.com/utdrmac/2125a8514960e163837e86bc934f19b6) script to keep your connections topped up.

Comment: Thank you! And could you explain what means unknown ancestors ?